# ImageView.setImageDrawable(null) not freeing memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, imageview

It appears that, when I call setImageDrawable(null) for an ImageView, the bitmap is not being released.  What can I do to force it to free the bitmap memory?

I have an activity that needs to display a large number of drawables, but not at the same time.  I have extended ImageView as shown here.  The XML layout file declares instances of this, with the "src" attribute set to "@null".  In replacement, I have a custom attribute to hold the drawable resource id.

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends ImageView
{
  int srcId = 0;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public ImageViewHolder (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super (context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes (attrs, R.styleable.ImageViewHolder, 0, 0);
    srcId = a.getResourceId (R.styleable.ImageViewHolder_src, 0);
    a.recycle();
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public void showDrawable (boolean makeVisible)
  {
    if (makeVisible)
    {
//      Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable (srcId);
//      setImageDrawable (d);
      setImageResource (srcId);
    }
    else // hide & free memory
    {
      Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getDrawable()).getBitmap();
      setImageResource(0);
      bitmap.recycle();
//      setImageDrawable (null);
    }
  }

}
```

I've tried using SetImagerResource() instead but get the same results.  I also tried calling System.gc() after clearing the drawable and that only deferred the point where my device ran out of memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can carefully try [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle())

Comment: Nice idea.  Didn't work - still get out-of-memory error.

Comment: how big are the bitmaps ? How many do you keep in memory? Are you using runtime cache?

Comment: They're about 600x800 pixels on the particular device I'm currently testing with.  I think the max case is displaying 3 of them at a time.  All the rest are supposed to be released, using the bit of code in my post.  I'm not doing any caching for these bitmaps - I'm adding the rest of the ImagveView extension for you to see.

Comment: 600*800 is not a big deal.. 1.8 mega bytes per bitmap... Of course you have to consider also the screen's density

Comment: True.  It doesn't run out of memory right away.  It happens after loading (and supposedly freeing) about 20 images.  I'll add that the deferred loading is definitely working.  Without, the whole activity crashes immediately with out of memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72530/discussion-between-peri-hartman-and-blackbelt).

Comment: I think I'm getting a clue of the problem. There is caching going on and it may be at the resource level. I just discovered that if I try to redisplay an ImageViewHolder whose bitmap has been recycled, I get the error: "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps". So, it appears that Resources is caching the bitmap once it loads it. I'll need to free it at that level or not load it via Resources (is that even possible?).

Comment: I can see that, after loading the 2nd time, that ImageView member  mBitmap.mRecycled = true.  Thus, even though I've called getResources().getDrawable(), the bitmap is not regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
setImageResource (srcId);
```

use

```
Resources r = getResources();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (r, srcId);
setImageBitmap (b);
```

This bypasses the Resources() caching and just recreates the bitmap each time you need it.  After testing this code, I'm still eventually getting an out-of-memory error but it's taking much longer to get there.  I'm going to assume it's being caused by something else.  For now, that's enough time spent on this problem :)